# Need help finding syntax error for MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax, syntax-error

I keep receiving a syntax error for the following code line using MYSQL 5.1

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['filter']) && (strlen($_REQUEST['filter']) > 0) && ($_REQUEST['filter'] == 'all')) {
$getqry = "SELECT * FROM ".$dbtbrestaurants."";
}
```

Can anyone help me understand why I an receiving a syntax error for the above code and help me fix this.

Thank you

Comment: What's the value of `$dbtbrestaurants`?

Comment: For a change I have to wonder why something got up-votes... :P

Comment: whats the use of `.""` at the last ?

Comment: @JonStirling $dbtbrestaurants points to which table to look for data in related to restaurants.

Comment: @tony What's the value of `$dbtbrestaurants`?

Comment: @tony Edit your question and add the value of: `var_dump($dbtbrestaurants);`. If you receive a mysql error also add that to your question.

Comment: @lU5er "" completes the line. Initially there was an ORDER by there example ("SELECT * FROM ".$dbtbrestaurants." ORDER by id")